# A guest subscribed to web push notification. How do I let him manage subscriptions?

Tags: push-notification, web-worker, web-push

A guest subscribed to web push notifications. I want to let him manage his notifications.

But how do I identify him? There must be some kind of ID I can retrieve on the client side and send it to the server to subscribe or unsubscribe this user from certain notifications topics.

I've tried this, but it looks like `getKey()` is for encryption, not for user identification. What is the right way to do manage subscriptions
?

```
pushManager.getSubscription()
  .then(subscription => {
    console.log('subscription.getKey()', subscription.getKey('p256dh'))
  })
```